# Cannot import cross_validation from sklearn in Python2

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I get the following error when I run bash:

```
shryanss-mbp-2:Desktop shryansgoyal$ python trash.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trash.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sklearn.cross_validation as cross_validation
ImportError: No module named cross_validation
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-validation for Sklearn 0.20+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273152/cross-validation-for-sklearn-0-20)

Answer (score 0):

DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20

for example:
if you want use "sklearn.cross_validation.KFold", use "sklearn.model_selection.KFold" instead.