# unable to import cross_validation

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

While building a new neural network, I seem unable to split the data.
For some unknown reason it won't import train.test.split

> ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation'

```
#split dataset in result y and data X
X = np.array(df.drop(['Survived'],1)) # not sure why this wasn't needed
y = np.array(df['Survived'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
```

I've tried various ways to import that sklearn function (outmarked):

```
#from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold
#from sklearn import module_selection # =>   cross_validation.train_test_split
#from sklearn import cross_validation
#from sklearn.svm.libsvm import cross_validation
#from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation

from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation
 #here are the machine algorythms
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier  
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB    #added myself (https://machinelearningmastery.com/compare-machine-learning-algorithms-python-scikit-learn/)
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
```

I'm a beginner in Python. I made manual (from scratch) neuralnets RNN LSTN in C#, but not in Python. Now I wanted to take the Kaggle Titanic challenge (so I cannot post all my code here, but i show this problem area only).

**Versions used:**

Python        :  3.6.6
Python        :  packaged by conda-forge
Python        :  (default, Jul 26 2018, 11:48:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Keras         :  configured for >  tensorflow 1.9.0
Panda         :  0.23.4
Numpy         :  1.15.2
Sklearn       :  0.20.0
Matplotlib    :  3.0.0

Additional note the function itself works in other Jupyter Notebooks using the same kernel (I even tried their import lines) but now it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-validation for Sklearn 0.20+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273152/cross-validation-for-sklearn-0-20)

Comment: No i dont think so the error i get is: 
ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation'

Comment: Just import `model_selection` in place of `cross_validation` and use `model_selection.train_test_split`.

Comment: And are you sure that when you say `"yes i'm sure both use the same Kernel TensorF"`, that means the other notebook also is actually importing `cross_validation` module and not commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about this, i was running a few jupyter notebooks.
Some at that moment were actively running tensor flow.
Even if i stopped them i couldnt run the new titanic kaggle task.
But after a reboot it al worked again.

I do hate such solutions because they leave me in the dark of what was the cause.
I doubt in general the stability of python environments, (i'm used to more stable C#), 
And I noticed that people have reported that paralelism doesnt work that well, so maybe a few notebooks side by side result in tensorflow problems.

```
Package             Version  
------------------- ---------
absl-py             0.5.0    
astor               0.7.1    
backcall            0.1.0    
certifi             2018.8.24
colorama            0.3.9    
cycler              0.10.0   
decorator           4.3.0    
gast                0.2.0    
grpcio              1.15.0   
h5py                2.8.0    
ipykernel           5.0.0    
ipython             7.0.1    
ipython-genutils    0.2.0    
jedi                0.13.1   
jupyter-client      5.2.3    
jupyter-core        4.4.0    
Keras               2.2.4    
Keras-Applications  1.0.4    
Keras-Preprocessing 1.0.2    
kiwisolver          1.0.1    
Mako                1.0.7    
Markdown            3.0.1    
MarkupSafe          1.0      
matplotlib          3.0.0    
mkl-fft             1.0.6    
mkl-random          1.0.1    
numpy               1.15.2   
pandas              0.23.4   
parso               0.3.1    
pickleshare         0.7.5    
pip                 18.1     
prompt-toolkit      2.0.5    
protobuf            3.6.1    
Pygments            2.2.0    
pygpu               0.7.6    
pyparsing           2.2.1    
pyreadline          2.1      
python-dateutil     2.7.3    
pytz                2018.5   
PyYAML              3.13     
pyzmq               17.0.0   
scikit-learn        0.20.0   
scipy               1.1.0    
setuptools          40.4.3   
simplegeneric       0.8.1    
sip                 4.19.12  
six                 1.11.0   
tensorboard         1.9.0    
tensorflow          1.9.0    
termcolor           1.1.0    
Theano              1.0.3    
tornado             5.1.1    
traitlets           4.3.2    
wcwidth             0.1.7    
Werkzeug            0.14.1   
wheel               0.32.1   
wincertstore        0.2
```

Comment: maybe you can check the kernel you used inside notebooks, such as the pip version and packages of the kernel installed. you can execute `! pip list` inside a notebook to check the package version.

Comment: @ShiXiuFeng i added all the used version do you notice something strange ? (btw thanks for that command pretty handy).

Comment: you mentioned "but its working in my other jupyter books", do these "other jupyter notebooks" run locally or remotely? do they share the same kernel with the current notebook?

Comment: its all on the same laptop, same kernel, (and it worked after reboot), its strange. Its no longer an urgent problem to me, (i can continue on kagle titanic now).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and figured out that it is a version issue

If you are using an older Version Jupiter notebook

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

or use this

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross validation, used to split training and testing data can be used as:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

then if X is your feature and y is your label, you can get your train-test data as:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=3)
```

where,

test_size: (multiply by 100) gives the percent of total data to be allocated for testing (i.e. here 30%)

random_state: is used to generate the SAME train-test split on any occassions, provided that other parameters remain same. This can be helpful for many people learning together so that they can get same final result which would obviously be depending on how data is split for training and testing

And finally this is the main source:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Answer (score 1):

For older Version--->
`from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split`

For New Version--->
`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

Answer (score -1):

The module has been removed since 0.20.

> Deprecated since version 0.18: This module will be removed in 0.20. Use sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score instead.

[image]

Comment: but its working in my other jupyter books, are you sure since you seam to talk about a score function (how well it behaves) while i am asking about a datasplit function.

Comment: @user613326 Check the environments for your other jupyter notebooks then. Are you sure you are using the same virtual environment for them?

Comment: @user613326 the `cross_validation` is the module which contains the function you used (datasplit), the module is Deprecated, the function is not important.  I doubt the environment of the jupyter notebook causes this issue, it may be helpful to learn to use virtualenv and other tools to manage your python packages.

Comment: i have no idea why my answer is downvoted, i think it is very clear.

Comment: @user613326, the tensorflow is just the backend of the keras framework, there is no connection between tf and sklearn. Are you doing the kaggle titanic task?

Comment: Yes i do the titanic task, but also 2 udemy courses (diabetic and breast cancer) those worked well and google lstm trading